# What devices do I need to boost my current?

Tags: arduino, current, current-source, wearable

my DC source can create a decent voltage (100-200 V), but the current is very low even when I do not install any resistance in the circuit. Therefore I want to find an external device that could generate a few miliamperes (only supply current and safe enough for human) and then connect with my source to generate enough electricity for an Arduino mainboard or a calculator.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly you have a high voltage low current power source and you require a low voltage 1 to 10 mA power source?

Comment: Yeah, you are definitely right, my current source is really low, only 1.4e-8 Amperes. I want a device that can supply more current that can be connected to my device.

Comment: For somebody that doesn't know what he is actually doing this is a pretty dangerous experiment. Buy/Use a decent power supply with protection circuit and skip this idea.

Comment: @ĐứcKhánh - Hi, You've asked some previous questions which are very similar to this one. How have you followed-on from those? What research have you done? [This](/a/624563) previous answer to one of your questions suggested you research the key phrase "energy harvesting" (since "normal" DC-DC converters won't run with such low currents). To avoid repeating answers already given to your earlier, related, questions, please [edit] your question and explain how this one is different from your previous ones, and how you have used previous answers / suggestions etc. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @SamGibson, I successfully lit up a hundred LEDs thanks to the circuit that everyone helped me with my previous question. However, when it came to some other electronic devices like digital thermometers or calculators, they did not work. I tried attaching many kinds of capacitors but they all failed. That's why I ask the new question.

Comment: @ĐứcKhánh - Thanks for your reply. You already got a previous answer suggesting you investigate the topic of "energy harvesting", since it is completely expected that devices will not operate correctly if the power source cannot supply the required current. Therefore, as suggested before, please [edit] your question and show how you have researched the previous recommendations. It is not a good use of everyone's time if you ask new questions without building on (and linking to) the answers you got to your previous, related, questions. I recommend you research energy harvesting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider how much power you have available, which appears to be about 2 or 3 uW. If the Arduino can run on that much power, and also drive whatever load you need, such as an LCD display, a low power buck converter could be designed. There are devices like watches that can run on microwatts. But an LED would need a few hundred uW to be visible. However, you might be able to store energy over some period of time in a capacitor, and then use it to provide several milliwatts for short intervals.

Comment: Actually, I sucessfully lit up a hundred of LEDs by connecting my device directly with a bridge rectifier. However, when I attach a capacitor between them, the LEDs did not light up like usual. So I do not know why it became like that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a DC to DC converter. You can search to see if there are some that operate on the 100V input, but this seems higher than usual so may not be a common component.

Comment: Actually, I can make my input lower, the only thing I need is to provide more current for the source. And can the DC to DC converter do that?

Comment: Look at power into the DC to DC converter P=IV, this is equal to power out minus some efficiency loss. So pick your output voltage and solve for I.